# Pandas groupby.sum for all columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset with a set of columns I want to sum for each row. The columns in question all follow a specific naming pattern that I have been able to group in the past via the .sum() function:

```
pd.DataFrame.sum(data.filter(regex=r'_name$'),axis=1)
```

Now, I need to complete this same function, but, when grouped by a value of a column:

```
data.groupby('group').sum(data.filter(regex=r'_name$'),axis=1)
```

However, this does not appear to work as the .sum() function now does not expect any filtered columns. Is there another way to approach this keeping my data.filter() code?

Example toy dataset. Real dataset contains over 500 columns where all columns are not cleanly ordered:

```
toy_data = ({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
         'group': ["a","a","b","b","c","c"],
         'a_name': [1,6,7,3,7,3],
         'b_name': [4,9,2,4,0,2],
         'c_not': [5,7,8,4,2,5],
         'q_name': [4,6,8,2,1,4]
    })
df = pd.DataFrame(toy_data, columns=['id','group','a_name','b_name','c_not','q_name'])
```

Edit: Missed this in original post. My objective is to get a variable ;sum" of the summation of all the selected columns as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter first and then pass `df['group']` instead `group` to `groupby`, last add `sum` column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df1 = (df.filter(regex=r'_name$')
         .groupby(df['group']).sum()
         .assign(sum = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)))
```

ALternative is filter columns names and pass after `groupby`:

```
cols = df.filter(regex=r'_name$').columns

df1 = df.groupby('group')[cols].sum()
```

Or:

```
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(r'_name$')]

df1 = df.groupby('group')[cols].sum().assign(sum = lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df1)
       a_name  b_name  q_name  sum
group                             
a           7      13      10   30
b          10       6      10   26
c          10       2       5   17
```

Comment: Thanks! sorry I missed this isn the post. I was hoping for the end output to be a sumed variable all the selected columns

Comment: @r_user - hmmm, can you add expected ouput? All columns are aggregated, how is aggregated `c_not`

Comment: posted, thanks!

Comment: @r_user - I got it, answer was EDIted.

Comment: Much appreciated!